# Get UTC offset and DST information for a specific timezone in node?

Tags: node.js, timezone, utc, dst, gmt

I need to get UTC offset and DST information for a specific timezone in node.js.
In case i use an external web service, it is necessary that the service used is free with unlimited requests if it's possible.

Example: if i put Europe/Rome timezone as a parameter i need to have 3600 as utc offset and 0 as DST information.

I found timezonedb but there is a rate limit where you can only send request to the server once per second.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only get an offset for a time zone *for a specific point in time*.  DST is not the only way in which time zones vary their offset over time.  Many have made changes to their standard time - sometimes multiple times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything time related you should look into using moment.js

[Here is the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for moment.js
[Here is the documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) for moment.js timezone

Below is taken from the moment.js timezone docs

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = moment("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 4am PST

jun.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 8am EDT
dec.tz('America/New_York').format('ha z');     // 7am EST
```

You should be able to find the correct methods based on your use case.

Comment: Thank you, i used these:

moment.utc().tz(zone_name).format('Z');
moment.utc().tz(zone_name).isDST();